# $A=2^3×5^2×7^3$ find number of divisors of A

Tags: algebra-precalculus, arithmetic, divisibility

My attempt :

$A=2^3×5^2×7^3$

Let's determine number of numbers primes with A, and
Smaller than A

$\rho (A) = 2^2 ×4×5×6×7^2 =23520$

23520 is a number of numbers primes with A and smaller than A

$\forall k$ $ \in {23520} $ $gcd(A, k)=1$

So : number of numbers doesn't prime white A is $A-23520=45080$

$\forall k $ $\in {45080} $ $gcd(A, k) ≠1$

let's search   about  The number of numbers that divide A

$A=0[k]$
$\Leftrightarrow$ $68600=0[k]$

In the first we can see  K can take the following values ${1,2,4, 5,7,8,10,20,40,50,70,100}$

After using this theory $(a=b[n] $and $a=b[m] $ and $gcd(m, n) =1$$\Rightarrow$ $a=b[MN] $)

We can see that

$K=(1, 2,4,5,7,8,10,20,40,50,70,100,35,56,28,14,140,280,350,700)$

So igot 20 value of k

But I know, there are 48 values of k

I want to know how can I continue for find 48 value of k

Note : I don't want any
other  solution, I want to develop of my attempt

Comment: Do you know about [Combinations with repetitions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combination#Number_of_combinations_with_repetition)?

Comment: @Tito Eliatron no I don't know

Comment: @Anaschaabi It is a good moment to learn about it

Comment: You forgot to include the numbers $3,13,21,34,51$ and some more in the list. I've checked your reasoning and I've found the 48 values you mention.

Comment: @Dog_69 but this number doesn't divide A

Comment: I suggest you find other methods if you're stuck. For example, we can prove that there are infinitely many primes by proving the twin prime conjecture (still unproven) or using a simple contradiction method.

Answer (score 1):

There is a simpler way. We can use the theorem for the number of divisors, where the number of divisors of $$p_1^{e_1}\cdot{p_2^{e_2}}\cdot{p_3^{e_3}}\ldots$$ is $$(e_1+1)(e_2+2)(e_3+3)\ldots$$

Putting that into your problem, $(3+1)(2+1)(3+1)=48$.

$A$ has $48$ divisors.

Comment: Yes I know that but I want just develop my attempt

Answer (score 1):

Let the prime factorization of $n$ be $n=p_1^{a_1}..p_n^{a_n}$.

Any prime factor of $n$, must be one of $p_1,..,p_n$. If $p_i$ is one of them, there are $i+1$ ways ($0,1,..,i$) to choose the exponent. So the number of factors is $(a_1+1)..(a_n+1)$.